# Kaggle Competition Submission API shows Notebook Threw Exception

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

In a kaggle [competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/mlb-player-digital-engagement-forecasting/overview) I have 5 submission limits. But my kernal is failing at submission again and again. It shows this status `Notebook Threw Exception`. According to kaggle:

> Due to the way Kaggle handles notebook runtime exceptions, this error
> class is currently only possible with scripts (not notebooks).

I tried in several ways to avoid `Notebook Threw Exception` but it is still nagging me. I'm stuck here for several days. I tried others' notebooks and tried to import their idea into mine. But still no clue why it is happening. Is it in my code or is it a bug in the submission API? What am I missing?

Here is my public kernal link:

https://www.kaggle.com/pritommojumder/fork-of-mlb-digital-forecasting?scriptVersionId=67691722

Comment: have you tried converting your notebook to a script and then to submit?

Comment: Since I'm new to kaggle competition then I may not understand you well. So pardon me. What do you mean by converting notebook to a script? I submit it through the `Submit Prediction` button. If it is well formatted then it takes the submission and if submission process succeed it give a public score. But my submission process is failing.

Comment: I myself didn't do much with kaggle yet, but from my perspective it seems there is an error in your Notebook, but kaggle isn't able to process this error. So here is the attempt I would start, with the knowledge that a Notebook is nothing else than a composition of text and code-script:
1. Move all code from the Notebook to a .py script file
2. Try to submit the script file instead of the Notebook.

Comment: I fear I can do that. Kaggle takes a submission as a notebook. Besides, it shows a log-message for a saved notebook. So if there is any problem in the notebook i would able to see in the log-message. But log-message is clean. And I've no submission left today as they only allow 5 submission per day. Would you try to run the notebook and submit it? Then I would able to know if it is only happening with me.

Comment: Did you noticed that "../input/derived-data/mean_target_by_player.csv" is not in your input dir? And also the weights?

Comment: I can see that it is there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234574/discussion-between-makanu-and-carl).

Comment: Sorry! I didn't notice that I had to make my files public. Can you see it now? I separated the training and prediction notebook just to reduce submission time and to see if it succeeds.